# Trigger for a Pro active reminder bot

Tags: c#, botframework

Hi I am making a reminder feature for a bot framework chat bot using c#.
What is the best trigger for a proactive reminder? I saw samples using task delay. is it applicable for reminder that can be set to 30 days from now or every 15 days? if I use a post API to send a proactive reminder. Is there a third party app that can trigger the post request with data coming from a database automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to use Task.Delay for the order of days - if you program dies during that time the reminder will be lost.

Usually you would store a DateTime for when the reminder should fire, then have a job that polls every so often and if the current DateTime is *after* that one, then it fires. This way it will survive reboots/changing instances etc. and as a bonus makes it easier to test your logic and change the reminder date and time after it is saved.

Comment: Should i save the date etc in CosmosDB and make an infinite loop that checks dates in cosmosDB every day?  Do you think that will work?

Comment: Yes I imagine that would work fine. Note - I'd probably look into WaitHandles like ManualResetEvent, instead of using an infinite loop, but yes probably something along those lines. It will depend how many notifications you expect to have firing on any given day what you do once you find notifications to actually fire